# Continuous extensions on discrete sets

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, continuity

I was looking for pointers in the right direction. The questions are as follows:

Consider the set $A = \left\{1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, ...\right\}$ and $N = \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$. Prove or disprove that a continuous function $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ must have a continuous extension to $B = \left\{0, 1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, ...\right\} = A \cup \{0\}$. Prove or disprove that a continuous function $f:N\to\mathbb{R}$ has a continuous extension to a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

In the second case with the set $N$ it seems that the statement is intuitively true since $N$ is closed and so $\mathbb{R}\setminus N$ is open. So, in some sense it would be easy to "draw" a smooth curve between these integer points on the open set $\mathbb{R}\setminus N$. On the other hand, every function $f$ is continuous on $N$ and so maybe there's some degenerate case where this is untrue. Otherwise, I'm fairly stumped.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: For $A$, show that *every* function from $A$ to $\Bbb R$ is continuous, and then find one that can’t be continuously extended to $0$. If you can’t, I’ve left a further hint in the spoiler-protected block:

> Try mapping $A$ to $N$ in a natural way.

Your intuition about $N$ is correct. You can make it rigorous by showing how to extend $f:N\to\Bbb R$ to a piecewise linear continuous function $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$. Just let $g(x)=f(1)$ for $x\le 1$, and show how to define $g$ on $[n,n+1]$ so that its graph is a straight line segment from $\langle n,f(n)\rangle$ to $\langle n+1,f(n+1)\rangle$.

Comment: Great pointers! Thank you.

Comment: @JohnMann: You’re welcome.